# End to end tracing of a flow from API/Scheduler in a Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, distributed-tracing

I am working with the Spring Boot application. I would like to add a `TraceId` to every request since it hits the application endpoint. In this context, I have added the dependency of `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth` similar to the following:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

I did not do any other changes. It is not solving the problem of tracing a request from end to end.

**1.** No `TraceId` is coming in the request access log. Now it's coming something like below

```java
[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] - - [09/Dec/2022:07:00:42 +0000] "GET /api/my-service/paginated?shared=false&size=15&page=0&isTemplate=false HTTP/1.1" 200 2121
```

As you can see, there is no trace id added to the log.

**2.** Secondly in the Hibernate query logs also, no `TraceId` is getting appended. One instance I am giving here for better understanding:

```
Hibernate: select myTable0_.name as nam1_22_0_ from myTable myTable0_ where myTable0_.name=?
```

**3.** Thirdly, in one request, I may need to call another service also owned by me, it's not getting propagated there as well. So, as of now, I am not able to trace any requests from end to end. This not only applies to APIs but also applies to schedulers as well. Could anyone please help here?

Comment: Sharing the relevant parts of your POM/gradle.build might get you the answer faster.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the log shared, it seems you have a custom logging pattern (maybe ?)

If thats right then you'll prolly need the [configuration as shown here](https://github.com/openzipkin-attic/sleuth-webmvc-example#configuration-tips) to see the traceId's in the logs.

Comment: After doing the changes as mentioned in the link, still the same, no trace id or span id in access log.